# How to display regular javascript in my React JS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to allow users to download songs to an audio playlist using input and FileReader() in regular javascript but nothing displays. I've already done most of my code in regular Javascript and I feel it might be difficult to transfer it into all ReactJS code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from "jquery";


var Download = (props) => {
    function other() {
      console.log("It's working");
      var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
      input.id = "upload-file";
      input.type = "file";
      input.multiple = true;

      var cloneInput = input.cloneNode(true);
      cloneInput.id = "cloneInput";

      var destinationDiv = document.createElement("div");
      destinationDiv.id = "destination";
      var destination = document.getElementById('destination');
      destinationDiv.innerHTML = "destination";

      var appendInput = document.body.appendChild(input);
      if (appendInput) {
        console.log("yay");
      }

      document.body.appendChild(destinationDiv);
      var inputId = document.getElementById('upload-file');
      if (inputId) {
        inputId.addEventListener('change', function() {
          var file;

          var destination = document.getElementById('destination');
          var audioAlreadyUsed = true;
          var ulAlreadyAdded = true;
          var alreadyUsed = true;
          // Looping in case they uploaded multiple files
          for (var x = 0, xlen = this.files.length; x < xlen; x++) {
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            file = this.files[x];
            a.innerHTML = file.name;
            console.log(file.name);
            if (file.type.indexOf('audio/mp3') != -1) { // Very primitive "validation"
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function(e) {
                var ul = document.createElement("UL");
                ul.id = "playlist";
                var audio = document.createElement("AUDIO");
                audio.id = "audio";
                // audio.src = e.target.result;
                audio.controls = true;
                audio.preload = "none";
                if (audioAlreadyUsed) {
                  destination.appendChild(audio);
                  audioAlreadyUsed = false;
                }
                if (ulAlreadyAdded) {
                  destination.appendChild(ul);
                  ulAlreadyAdded = false;
                }
                var li = document.createElement("LI");
                li.class = "active";
                li.id = "liID";
                var clone = li.cloneNode(true);
                document.getElementById("playlist").appendChild(clone);
                a.href = e.target.result;
                clone.appendChild(a);
                //PLAYLIST CODE
                var audio;
                var playlist;
                var tracks;
                var current;
                var len;
                var link;
                var par;

                init();

                function init() {
                  current = 0;
                  audio = $('audio');
                  playlist = $('#playlist');
                  tracks = playlist.find('li a');
                  len = tracks.length - 1;
                  audio[0].volume = .10;
                  // audio[0].play();

                  playlist.find('a').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    link = $(this);
                    current = link.parent().index();
                    run(link, audio[0]);
                  });
                  audio[0].addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
                    current++;
                    if (current == len) {
                      current = 0;
                      link = playlist.find('a')[0];
                    } else {
                      link = playlist.find('a')[current];
                    }
                    run($(link), audio[0]);
                  });
                }

                function run(link, player) {
                  player.src = link.attr('href');
                  par = link.parent();
                  par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                  audio[0].load();

                  // Show loading animation.
                  var playPromise = audio[0].play();

                  if (playPromise !== undefined) {
                    playPromise.then(_ => {
                        // Automatic playback started!
                        // Show playing UI.
                        // We can now safely pause video...
                        audio.pause();
                      })
                      .catch(error => {
                        // Auto-play was prevented
                        // Show paused UI.
                      });
                  }
                };
              };
              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            };
          }
        });
      };
    };
    return ( < div > {
        other()
      } < /div>)
    };
    export default Download;
```

I've been stuck on this for quite some time now. My code runs in the console but nothing displays on the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: at this point, why even use react?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow and read how to ask a question to let us help you the best https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. More over as i see you need read more theory of js and react exactly. Because your question is very complicated and must be broken into pieces

Comment: Your question doesn't exactly make sense.  Javascript is a **Language**.  React.js is a **Framework** written in that language.  Therefore, it is not different from "regular Javascript", and isn't the reason your code isn't functioning.

Comment: Did you just wrap your original code in a React functional component and hope it would work? Well, sorry, it won't. You need to take a look at the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) to get a feel for how React works, perhaps by building a small component first. Then there are _lots_ of tutorials on the net for you to look at. Then, when you have questions about that code, come back to SO and we'll be able to help. But this question is far too broad as it stands.

Comment: That being said, there are some things that React does to stop you from accessing the DOM directly, so using React and some other Framework or code that directly manipulates the DOM on the same page might not play well nicely together.

Comment: You guys think I should copy this code and turn it into a React JS component or just look up a whole different tutorial?

Comment: Are there any good tutorials on how to do what I'm doing here with React? Thanks guys.

Comment: "Are there any good tutorials on how to do what I'm doing here"  That's a great question.  However, it's not a question that is appropriate for this site.  This site is about helping people **solve their programming problems**, not **write code** or **teach programming concepts**. Tutorials are off topic, because they generally are at best opinionated and at worst, spam.  as @AlexNikonov stated, the problem you are trying to solve should be tackled in pieces, and just throwing a tutorial down with a bunch of code isn't going to help you with the fundamentals of the problem.

Comment: in other words, stop trying to write an app by copying other people's code from tutorials, it never leads to a good place.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the body of this questioning appearing to deviate from the title, I am going to tackle the problem within the title: **How do I import javascript files into my react components?**

The answer is pretty simple. I chose to make a directory structure of:

1. `./dummyDir`
2. `./dummyDir/react-src/`
3. `./dummyDir/react-src/src`

This all can be seen within reactjs.org. And then, all of your react/javascript specific code will go in `.../src/`. So, you will have `./dummyDir/react-src/src/myJSFile.js`

There are two more steps. The next step is being sure that you `import` the javascript and any classes (assuming you do some oop) into your `.jsx` file. Now, you can call any of the methods within your old javascript files right into your react components.

The last step is hosting and deploying. I won't go over hosting as much as hosting to a local environment. I test host with apachectl on my local machine, for example. If that is the case for you, you might get hung up on not hosting from `npm run serve` as it looks like you are trying to plugin react instead of start with react.

Thus, you will want a bash script with something like this:

```
deploy () {
  if [ ! -d build/ ]
  then
    echo -e "ERROR:\n\tDoes not appear to be correct directory;"
    echo -e "\tDir /build/ not found;"
    return 1
  fi  
  echo -e "STARTING:"

  # Testing if build failed...
  npm run build
  if [ ! $? -eq 0 ] ; 
    then
      printf "\nnpm run build has failed...\n"
      printf "\npreserving previous ./build/\n"
      return 2
  fi  

  if [ -d ../static/ ]
  then
    echo -e "\tREMOVING ../static/*"
    rm -r ./../static/ || echo "\tWARNING: DID NOT REMOVE DIR"
  else
    echo -e "\tDID NOT FIND ../static/ FOR REMOVAL"
  fi  

  # Redirecting the ls output to make it completely silent
  if ls ../precache-manifest* 1> /dev/null 2>&1;
  then
    echo -e "\tREMOVING ../precach*"
    rm -r ./../precache-manifest*  || echo "\tWARNING: DID NOT REMOVE CACHE"
  else
    echo -e "\tDID NOT FIND ../static/ FOR REMOVAL"
  fi  

  echo -e "\tRUNNING: npm run build"

  echo -e "\tCOPYING OVER NEW BUILD DIR"
  cp -r build/* ../ 

  echo -e "DONE"
  return 0  #Bash is weird; 0 is true, 1 is false;
}
```